# Facebook sharer.php with custom param shows good preview posts bad post, what am i doing wrong/changed? it worked in october

Tags: facebook, overriding, facebook-opengraph, linkshare

FIXED:

is a known facebook bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1408009512775909

---

original post:

I'm sharing a link through:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://site&p[images][0]=urltoimg&p[summary]=summery&p[title]=title

when i use the url it shows a perfect preview (all my custom stuff is there). But when i click share, it uses the shared sites opengraph crawled information.

This exact method worked in 2013 (okt/nov/dec).

Does anybody know what changed? Or what i'm doing wrong?

How can i override the crawled info?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

From 2014 in such cases better to use "Feed and Share dialogs":

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#redirect

Example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=145634995501895
&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption 
&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fdialogs%2F
&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

Link to parameters:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#params

Comment: Sweet! I never knew that they changed the URL. I'm glad that it's still possible